# How to upload large csv file into mysql fastly in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, csv

I am using codeigniter framework. I want to upload larg csv file into mysql database fastly. The file contains 87000 rows. I have added for uploading the data, but it is loading morethan 1 hour. i need to optimize this time.Please suggest me.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_content']['tmp_name'],$path.$actual_file_name))
            {
if (($handle = fopen($path.$actual_file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {               
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,100000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
$insert_batch=array(    
'unique_transactionid' => mb_check_encoding($data[0], 'UTF-8') ? $data[0] : utf8_encode($data[0]),
'data-year' => mb_check_encoding($data[2], 'UTF-8') ? $data[2] : utf8_encode($data[2]),
'supplier_group' => mb_check_encoding($data[4], 'UTF-8') ? $data[4] : utf8_encode($data[4]),
);
this->db->insert('table name', $insert_batch);
}
}
}
```

I need the data is uploading fastly. Currently our server max_excecution time is 10 mins. It excecutes more than 10 mins and the page is not redirect to my page and at last i got page not found error. Please help me to upload fastly.

Answer (score 0):

take the `insert()` function out of the while loop and use `batch_insert()` instead. What you are doing right now, is creating the array and insert, for each of the rows.

```
$i=0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,100000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
  $insert_batch[$i]=array(    
    'unique_transactionid' => mb_check_encoding($data[0], 'UTF-8') ? $data[0] : utf8_encode($data[0]),
    'data-year' => mb_check_encoding($data[2], 'UTF-8') ? $data[2] : utf8_encode($data[2]),
    'supplier_group' => mb_check_encoding($data[4], 'UTF-8') ? $data[4] : utf8_encode($data[4]),
  );
  $i++;
}
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $insert_batch);
```

Comment: well, not in your code example: there the insert() function is within the while loop

Comment: If we add insert() function outside of while loop only one row will insert into my database. I want to insert all rows in the csv file.

Comment: @user9456654 I've updated my answer, I mistakenly forgot to use the insert_batch() function.